# Syntax Error in Insert Into statement, inserting data into specific columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I need help with the syntax for inserting data into specific columns in a table in MS Access, depending on the selected choice from a dropdownlist in asp.net C#. I was planning on passing the name of the column in the table where i'll add the data.

```
protected void BTNsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Order was successfull!');</script>");

            if (DDLselectedProduct.SelectedItem.Text == "Tide Wave Burger") AddToDatabase("No_TideWave");
            else if (DDLselectedProduct.SelectedItem.Text == "Burger Meaty Delight") AddToDatabase("No_BurgerMeaty");
            else if (DDLselectedProduct.SelectedItem.Text == "Darkness Mushroom Burger") AddToDatabase("No_Darkness");
            else if (DDLselectedProduct.SelectedItem.Text == "Macaroni Burger") AddToDatabase("No_Macaroni");
            else if (DDLselectedProduct.SelectedItem.Text == "Cheesy Burger Delight") AddToDatabase("No_Cheesy");
            else if (DDLselectedProduct.SelectedItem.Text == "Amazing Bacon Delight") AddToDatabase("No_Amazing");
            else if (DDLselectedProduct.SelectedItem.Text == "Love Me Now Burger") AddToDatabase("No_Love");
            else Response.Write("<script>alert('Something went wrong!');</script>");
        }

        protected void AddToDatabase(string burgerType)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Burgerlight.mdb"));
            connection.Open();
            
            OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand($"insert into Order (Cus_lastname,Cus_firstname,Cus_Tel_no,Cus_address,Cus_zipcode,Cus_province,Cus_city,{burgerType},Type_Trans,Total_Bill) values ('{TXTlname.Text}','{TXTfname.Text}','{TXTtelephone.Text}','{TXTaddress.Text}','{TXTzipcode.Text}','{TXTprovince.Text}','{TXTcity.Text}','{TXTqty.Text}','{DDLdelivery.SelectedValue}','{TXTtotal.Text}');", connection);
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

I can't seem to find the reason why it keeps getting a syntax error in the Insert Into statement. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: `{burgerType}` in your INSERT column selection seems off to me, for starters.

Comment: Can you capture the INSERT query generated and share here?

Comment: The {burgerType} variable is the name of the column in which I want to add the TXTqty.Text. I am not sure what you mean by capturing the INSERT query generated, but these are supposedly the columns for my Order table:

Cus_lastname 
Cus_firstname 
Cus_Tel_no 
Cus_address 
Cus_zipcode 
Cus_province
Cus_city
No_TideWave 
No_BurgerMeaty
No_Darkness
No_Macaroni
No_Cheesy
No_Amazing 
No_Lovet
Type_Tran
Total_Bill

Comment: I don't see replies unless you @ me.  Regarding capturing the query, the error would be obvious if we could see the exact T-SQL insert command being ran (which is generated by your code).  Basically, the resulting insert string before it's executed.  Granted, might need the schema if the insert query looks fine.  Finally, please post error details.

Comment: Access SQL does not use apostrophe delimiters for number field parameter. If TXTqty and TXTtotal are number type, try removing the apostrophes.

Comment: Hello! Turns out my code works fine if I changed the table name. I think it didn't work with the table name 'Order' because it's a reserved keyword? Thank you for taking the time to reply though!